# Is it possible to "hook" Logitech functions?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, logitech-mouse

I'm wondering if it's possible to somehow hook Logitech Setpoint shortcut functions, like volume change?

I have both a Logitech keyboard and mouse. On the keyboard, there are buttons for changing the volume (up/down/mute). Is it possible to somehow "hook" or use those Logitech functions elsewhere, besides purely being tied to that keyboard button?

To explain these functions to those that don't use Logitech devices (or Setpoint) -- when you press one of the non-standard buttons, like volume-up, for example, a small Logitech window fades up on the screen, showing you the action/button pressed.

Comment: Don't you have a related question like this already?

Comment: At a guess, AutoHotKey would be able to see these keys (they're probably normal "extended" keys for multimedia things etc) and you'd treat them like any other key press.